# Equivalent definition of algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In Hungerford's Algebra text, it is stated that a field $K$ is algebraically closed iff
there exists a subfield $F$ such that $K$ is algebraic over $F$ and all polynomials in $F[x]$ split in $K[x]$.   This seems to be a much weaker condition that $K$ being algebraically closed.  I don't see why it is true (it is not proven in the text)

Is there a particular reason why this is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. The minimal polynomial splits over $K$. Thus, $\alpha \in K$.

So this is quite immediate. However, there is even a weaker condition: Every non-constant polynomial in $F[x]$ has *some root* in $K$. Then it also follows that $K$ is algebraically closed; but this is a nontrivial theorem (Isaacs, *Roots of polynomials in algebraic extensions of fields*; or: Gilmer, *A Note on the Algebraic Closure of a Field*).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\bar{K}$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ and fix $\alpha\in \bar{K}$. Then $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ because algebraic extensions are transitive. In particular this implies that the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ splits in $K[x]$ so that $\alpha \in K$. So we have $K=\bar{K}$ and $K$ is algebraically closed.